# Spark application terminating due to Error" Signal Term"

Tags: apache-spark

I am running an spark application for 350 GB and getting error of Signal Term in yarn logs. Here are some configuration of Spark I have.

Executor memory : 50 GB
Driver Memory : 50 GB
Memory Overhead : 6 GB
Number of cores per Executor: 5

I am not able to find a root cause and solution. Please help

Comment: can you try this and analyse the logs for more clarification  
`yarn logs -applicationId [app_id]`

Comment: Above logs are from yarn only